# Count day of week between dates from another column in excel

Tags: excel

Consider the following sheet:

```
        A        B      C    D      E
  --------------------------------------- 
  |                        Non
  | Start    End      Mon  Mon
 1| Date     Date     Vac  Vac  Vacation
  |                   Days Days Days 
 2| 11/16/17 11/30/17   1   2   11/21/2017
 3| 12/1/17  12/15/17   0   0   11/22/2017
 4| 12/16/17 12/31/17   0   4   11/27/2017
 5|                             12/26/2017
 6|                             12/27/2017
 7|                             12/28/2017
 8|                             12/29/2017
```

What formula can I put in cells C2:D4 to get the values needed?

Notes:

- The formula should only lists those vacation days in column E:E that are in the range of A2&B2 (if solving for C2 and D2)
- In this example only vacation date 11/27/2017 is a Monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might the following work in C2?

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY($E$2:$E$8,2)=1),--($E$2:$E$8>=A2),--(‌​$E$2:$E$8<=B2))
```

Here it is deployed in sheet with UK date format:

[image: data]

Comment: It works for C2 but for C3 AND C4, it gives the same answer (1) instead of "0".  I changed the A2 & B2 to be rows 3 and 4 respectably.

Comment: I did for A2 & B2, changed to  A3 & B3 on C3, and A4 & B4 on C4.

Comment: I did the drag down (autofill) but I end up with 1,1,1 instead of 1,0,0

Comment: Actually, I had different dates for columns A & B, (why I don't know). When I changed it to the exact dates as in the sample above, I ended up with 2,1,1 which is even stranger.

Comment: Actually if I copy your formula exactly as it is, it gives me an error and try to correct itself. I end up with this formula: "=SUMPRODUCT(--WEEKDAY($E$2:$E$8,2)=1)--($E$2:$E$8>=A2)--($E$2:$E$8<=B2)"  Notice the missing last quote on the fixed one.

Comment: The formula you put down is not exactly like the one in the picture. Here is the differences:

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY($E$2:$E$8,2)=1),--($E$2:$E$8>=A2),--($E$2:$E$8<=B2))

Comment: updated. Hopefully that is now consistent. Thanks for spotting. If ok please consider accepting as answer. Box at top left (green arrow).